# Using wget (for windows) to download all MIDI files

Tags: wget

I've been trying to use wget to download all midi files from a website (http://cyberhymnal.org/) using:

```
wget64 -r -l1 H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.mid -erobots=off http://cyberhymnal.org/
```

I got the syntax from various sites which all suggest the same thing, but it doesn't download anything. I've tried various variations on the theme, such as different values for '-l' etc.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Is it the fact that I am using Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about all the parameters you are using like **H**, **-t1**, **-N** etc though we can find it online. But I also had to download files from a url matching a wildcard. So command that worked for me:

wget -r -l1 -nH --cut-dirs=100 -np "$url" -P "${newLocalLib/$tokenFind}"  -A "com.iontrading.arcreporting.*.jar"

after -P you specify the path where you wanna save the files to and after -A you provide the wild card token. Like in your case that would be "*.mid".

-A means **Accept**. So here we provide the files to accept from the provided URL. Similarly -R for reject list.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck (at least, you'll get more MIDI files), if you try the actual Cyber Hymnal™, which moved over 10 years ago. The current URL is now http://www.hymntime.com/tch/.